# Elementwise operations over tuples in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Are there any built-in functions that allow elementwise operations over tuples in Python 3?  If not, what is the "pythonic" way to perform these operations?

Example:  I want to take the percent difference between `a` and `b` and compare them to some threshold `th`.

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 4)
>>> b = (1.1, 2.1, 4.1)
>>> # compute pd = 100*abs(a-b)/a = (10.0, 5.0, 2.5)
>>> th = 3
>>> # test threshold: pd < th => (False, False, True)
```

Comment: are we talking about the map function? http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html#map

Comment: combined with zip? http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

map function

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 4)
>>> b = (1.1, 2.1, 4.1)
>>> map(lambda a,b: 100*abs(a-b)/a < 3, a, b)
[False, False, True]
```

**EDIT**

of course instead of map, you can use list comprehensions, like BrenBarn did  http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions

**EDIT 2** zip removed, thanks for DSM to point it out that zip is not needed

Comment: You don't need `zip` here; you could write `map(lambda a,b: 100*abs(a-b)/a < 3, a, b)`.  [Note this function accepts two arguments, not one 2-tuple.]

Comment: `map(lambda (a, b) : 100*abs(a-b)/a < 3, a, b)` => `TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: @DSM Could but maybe shouldn't. I detest shortcuts that allow merging another higher-order function into another via overloads (very common in LINQ, e.g. `.First(cond)` instead of `.Where(cond).First()`), because it is never obvious to me *which* operation is implied (map? zip? filter? something else?).

Comment: `map(lambda (a, b) : 100*abs(a-b)/a < 3, (a, b))` => `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: @bpgergo: please reread my comment, especially the parts in brackets.

Comment: @DSM, hope you don't mind if I update my answer and remove an unnecessary `zip`. And thanks for pointing this out. I always learn something, especially if someone is patient enough to catch my shallow focus.

Comment: @bpgergo: I'd leave your answer as it is -- it works just fine, and the comment is there for anyone to see anyway.

Comment: Note that as it's Python 3, the map will actually return a generator rather than a list. If you want a list, either wrap it in list() or (simpler) use a list comprehension with zip (as BrenBarn did).

Comment: If you want it "Pythonic" then list comprehension with zip would be better than the map-based solution. I thought at one stage they were seriousely thinking of moving map to a module so it would need to be imported to be used in Python 3.

Answer (score 12):

There is no builtin way, but there is a pretty simple way:

```
[f(aItem, bItem) for aItem, bItem in zip(a, b)]
```

. . . where `f` is the function you want to apply elementwise.  For your case:

```
[100*abs(aItem - bItem)/aItem < 3 for aItem, bItem in zip(a, b)]
```

If you find yourself doing this a lot, especially with long tuples, you might want to look at `Numpy`, which provides a full-featured system of vector operations in which many common vector functions (basic operations, trig functions, etc.) apply elementwise.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use NumPy?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,4])
b = np.array([1.1, 2.1, 4.1])

pd = 100*abs(a-b)/a # result: array([ 10. ,   5. ,   2.5])
th = 3
pd < th # result: array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an operation like that, perhaps some of the functional programming features of Python would work (map? reduce?), though putting together a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (or generator if the list is not needed) is relatively straight forward:

```
[100*abs(j-b[i])/j < 3 for i,j in enumerate(a)]
[False, False, True]
```

Thanks to @delnan for pointing out a very nice simplification for the original, more explicit/verbose version:

```
[True if 100*abs(j-b[i])/j < 3 else False for i,j in enumerate(a)]
```

Comment: `True if 100*abs(j-b[i])/j < 3 else False` -> `100*abs(j-b[i])/j < 3`

Comment: @delnan Ah .. got it!! Very nice!! .. thanks, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @delnan `bool` doesn't seem to be necessary

Comment: Actually I thought you put in the `True` and `False` to follow the "explicit is better than implicit" rule. I often find myself wondering which way to go in these circumstances.

Comment: @Ghopper21 Well, that's the way I thought of it first, but I do like the shorter version better. Maybe I should list both?

Comment: Yeah, I slightly prefer the way you had it originally, but I'm not sure which would be considered more Pythonic...

Comment: @Ghopper21 I think it's pretty clear that it results in a boolean if you notice the comparison operator. A way to read e.g. `[x > 3 for x xs]` is: The ith output denotes *whether* the ith input is greater than 3.

Comment: @Levon Yes, `bool` is not necessary, I got tripped up for a second.

Comment: @delnan -- yep, I often use this implicit boolean style, but I'm still torn about it, as the other way is, after all, more explicit.

Comment: @delnan Thanks for the reply (and the original suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

I would say the Pythonic way is with list comprehension:

When `a = (1, 2, 4)` and `b = (1.1, 2.1, 4.1)`

then, in one line:

```
TEST = [100*abs(a[i]-b[i])/a[i] > th for i in range(len(A))]
```

Comment: This will evaluate the fn on the Cartesian product of A and B, not elementwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
def pctError(observed, expected):
    return (observed-expected)/expected * 100.0

a = (1, 2, 4)
b = (1.1, 2.1, 4.1)
th = 3

pctErrors = map(lambda t:pctError(*t), zip(a,b))
# returns [-9.091, -4.76, -2.44]

map(lambda x: x < th, pctErrors)
[x < th for x in pctErrors]
# both return [True, True, True]

# or if you always need absolute % errors
map(lambda x: abs(x) < th, pctErrors)
[abs(x) < th for x in pctErrors]
# both return [False, False, True]
```